# What is the expected value E(X), E(Y), Var (X,Y)

Tags: mean, expected-value, independence

Suppose there are three cards labeled with values 1, 2, and 3, and two of them are chosen at random (without replacement). Let the random variable $X$ be the value on the first card chosen, and let random variable $Y$ be the value on the second.

I understand that the expected value of the first drawn card, $E(X) = \frac{1}{3}(1) + \frac{1}{3}(2) + \frac{1}{3}(3) = 2$. However, I don't understand the second random variable $E(Y)$ value because it depends on the first one.

Comment: E(Y) = E(X) because E(Y) covers exactly the same values with exactly the same probabilities as E(X)

Comment: Have you tried listing the sample space? It might help you see why $E(Y)$ doesn't depend on $X$ unless you have observed $X$ and take account of that (i.e. are looking at $E(Y|X)$).

Comment: To see how much sampling without replacement might change expectations, let's push your example to its furthest extreme: draw a third card without replacement.  It's the last one chosen.  Isn't it clear that each card has an equal chance of being the last?  Therefore the expectation of the third card is the same as the expectation of the first card.

Answer (score 2):

$$E(Y)=E(X)$$

or to put it another way

$$
\begin{array}
EE(Y) & = & \sum_{x=1}^3{E(Y|X=x)P(X=x)} \\
 & = & \sum_{x=1}^3{E(Y|X=x)} \frac{1}{3}\\
 & = &  \frac{1}{3} \sum_{x=1}^3{E(Y|X=x)} \\
 & = & \frac{1}{3}  (2.5 + 2 + 0.5) \\
 & = &2
\end{array}
$$